# Cómo puedo obtener datos de una columna con varias filas de datagridview y guardar en SQL server

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un problema, quisiera guardar la columna de varias filas de un dgv  en la base de datos sql... Ejemplo
 En la dgv

```
|ID | | Detalle |.                                                                                            
 1      Polo.                                                                                                    
 2      Camisa.                                                                                                 
 3     Bermuda
```

Quisiera guardarlo en mi tabla de SQL de esta manera

```
|ID | |Detalle|.                                                                                                                                                                     
  1      polo, camisa , bermuda
```

Espero haberme explicado

Lo estoy realizando en c#

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que des el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio y de paso ganar tu primer medalla, también podrías revisar [ask] para que formules de mejor manera tu pregunta y esta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Porque querrias hacer eso? no suena que este bien. podrias explicar un poco mas el razonamiento atras de esto?

Comment: Hola, supongo que necesitaras eso para algun caso de poner todas las etiquetas en un campo o algo así. Lo que necesitas, por lo que entiendo, solo es recorrer el grid y meter todos los datos en un string, por ejemplo, luego ese string lo insertas en la base de datos y listo. Si es lo que necesitas y quieres el codigo, dime que te lo envio sin problema

Comment: Me serviría para mi libro de conocimientos bro,